# Custom authentication on IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

I'm digging into building an identity server using IdentityServer4, and I have some business logic that i want to implement on password change, and on password persist.
On the asp.net core page built into the IdentityServer that I've made using the [startups](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/index.html), I can achieve it on the controllers provided, ok.
But, I wanted to be able to change the password check for a token grant to a windows client or mobile client for example,these clients won't do the login from the asp.net page.

How can I acheive this?

Comment: I am not too sure what you are asking. But it sounds like you want to have login for your windows client or mobile client but not from your IdentityServers SSO login page? Why do you want to do this? It is possible to login via windows gui client or mobile client by the way...

Comment: I thought it was not possible to use the sso login page from these platforms. Do you have some links on that?

Comment: Depends on what platform youre doing it on.
All you do is pop open a browser instance from the application (you can do this on windows and on mobile). All you need to do to find examples is google "OAuth/OpenIDConnect + Platform" you will find a library or example to put you in the right direction.

Comment: I've found some answers like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462264/openid-in-winform) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903996/openid-connect-using-identityserver-for-sso-between-winforms-and-web-applicati)   ....  So I think I'll setup a client with password grant and use IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator to make custom check.

Comment: Fair enough, would recommend you do hybrid flow for mobile though.